# Suppress condition for Page N of M for last page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have added special field `Page N of M` in the crystal report. I want to suppress this field when it is last page and when only one page is there.

For example, if there is only 1 page, the field `Page N of M` should not be displayed. If there are 5 pages, the field `Page N of M` should only be displayed for the first 4 pages.

What should I give in the suppress condition to suppress this field?

Answer (score 9):

So you don't want Page N of M to be displayed on the last page? Try

```
PageNumber = TotalPageCount
```

in your Suppress formula.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to suppress page numbers when there is only one page, It may not be desirable to always suppress the last page number (as answered by MartW). A better suppress condition would be:

```
TotalPageCount=1
```

This also works well when you reset page count for groups.